# How to override generic list return type in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to override the method which return type as list in sub class like as below example, due to generics issue i can not able to do it in my sub class. I can not able to change my super class code, so how i can resolve the issue? any one can please guide me...many thanks in advance.

**Super classes which can not be update:**

```
public class Animal {
           private String legs;
    }

public class TestSuper {

    public List<Animal> addAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }
}
```

**Sub classes:**

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
         private String sound;
    }

public class TestSub extends TestSuper {

    public List<Dog> addAnimals() { --> I need to override this method but want return type as List of dogs
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only override the return type with an assignment-compatible type. However, generics are not covariant. `List<Dog>` is not a subtype of `List<Animal>`. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type).

Answer (score 12):

If the super classes really can't be updated, I'm afraid you simply can't.

**If you had been able to update the super classes:**

In `TestSuper`, you would have use `public List<? extends Animal> addAnimals()` instead of `public List<Animal> addAnimals()`.

**What other solution(s) do you have:**

You could use such a utility method:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Animal> List<T> cast(List<Animal> animals, Class<T> subclass) {
    List<T> out = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Animal animal : animals) {
        if (!subclass.isAssignableFrom(animal.getClass())) {
            // the "animal" entry isn't an instance of "subclass"
            // manage this case however you want ;)
        } else {
            out.add((T) animal);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then, to call:

```java
List<Dog> dogs = TheClassNameYouChose.cast(animals, Dog.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i dot have that option in my project, due to that reason expecting the suggestions :(

Comment: wanted to use the addAnimals() which is there in super class...hence i am trying to override

Comment: @Satya Yes, I got it, and the idea was good, but if you can't change the signature of the `TestSuper#addAnimals()` method, it's simply not possible...

Answer (score 3):

If `Dog` is a subclass of `Animal`, you could possibly do

The following signature:

```
public List<? extends Animal> addAnimals()
```

Then do

```
public List<Dog> addAnimals()
```

in the sub class.

Or you could make the super class generic `<T>` and the implementing class `<Dog>`

Answer (score 2):

You cant change generic type of List to subtype of that generic type. Problem is that reference to any instance can be subtype of that instance. So lets have a look at this example

```
SuperType sup = new SubType();
sup.getAnimals().add(new Cat());
//adding cat is possible because getAnimals() returns List<Animal>
```

So you would add `Cat` to list that should contain only `Dogs`, which is wrong.

---

Also in overridden method you cant change generic type of list to list with supertype of that generic type (like `List<Dog>` to `List<Animal>`). Why? Lets take a look at this example

```
SuperType sup = new SubType();
Dog d = sup.getAnimals().get(0);
```

In subtype we have list of Animals so it is possible that `get(0)` will return Cat.

---

If you can change code in your classes then try maybe this approach

```
class Super<T extends Animal> {
    public List<T> addAnimals() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Sub extends Super<Dog> {

    @Override
    public List<Dog> addAnimals() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make the TestSuper use generics to really make this work correctly.

```
TestSuper<T extends Animal> {

  public List<T> addAnimals() {

  }
}

TestSub extends TestSuper<Dog> {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The super class contract says that if you have:

```
class Animal {}
class Dog extends Animal {}
class Cat extends Animal {}
```

The following code **must** be valid:

```
TestSuper test = new AnySubclassOfTestSuper(); // including TestSub!
test.addAnimals().add(new Cat());
```

Your override in the `TestSub` class would violate that, since you can't add a `Cat` to a `List<Dog>`. Since it'd be a violation of a fairly fundamental principle of object-oriented type systems, you're not going to find a perfect workaround for this restriction.

The suggestions to change the superclass to use `List<? extends Animal>` would work because you can't add anything to that list.