# How to override findElements method so it returns list of type that implements WebElement interface

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wrapper

There is an interface WebElement.

I want to make a wrapper UIElement, that implements WebElement.

I've overridden all methods.

But faced one problem with **findElementS** method that returns **List<WebElement>**. I've tried to change return type to **List<UIElement>**, but code returns an error: "*attempting to use incompatible return type*". And it's weird for me, because it was not a problem to override **findElement** method and specify **UIElement** as return type.

Here is my method that IDE doesn't give to use with error from above:

```
List<UIElement> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (WebElement el : this.element.findElements(by)) {
        UIElement uiElement = new UIElement(this.driver, el);
        list.add(uiElement);
    }
    return list;
```

Here is UIElement class and constructors:

```
public class UIElement implements WebElement {
private final WebDriver driver;
private final WebElement element;
private final Actions actions;
private final JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor;
private final Waiter waiter;


public UIElement(WebDriver driver, By by) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.element = this.driver.findElement(by);
    this.actions = new Actions(this.driver);
    this.jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    this.waiter = new Waiter(this.driver);
}

public UIElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    this.driver = driver;
    this.element = element;
    this.actions = new Actions(this.driver);
    this.jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    this.waiter = new Waiter(this.driver);
}
}
```

Comment: change `List<UIElement> list = new ArrayList<>();`
to `List<UIElement> list = new ArrayList<UIElement>();`

Comment: @pburgr nope, it didn't help

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish by creating `UIElement`? It seems to me that you are jamming a bunch of stuff that has nothing to do with an element into that wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the "List of Webelement" to "List of UIElement" in the overrided method.

You cant change generic type of List to subtype of that generic type. Problem is that reference to any instance can be subtype of that instance

Refer this link for more details- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275774/how-to-override-generic-list-return-type-in-java)