# Chaining, returning base objects, and type mismatch to extended classes

Tags: java, types, polymorphism

I have come across a class like this. It holds a "with" method that lets people chain things together.

```
public class Bear {
    protected List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    protected List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Bear withName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
        return this;
    }

    public Bear withFood(String food) {
        foods.add(food);
        return this;
    }
}

// ...somewhere else
Bear b = new Bear().withName("jake").withName("fish");
```

I found two classes that shared 90% of the same code. So, I created a base class between them, and transferred the 25 or so "with" methods to it (with the member variables and all.) Like so:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Animal withName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
        return this;
    }
}

public class Bear extends Animal {
    protected List<String> foods = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Bear withFood(String food) {
        foods.add(food);
        return this;
    }
}
```

However, this now breaks everything (And there is a lot of places that use this with design for these two classes).

```
Bear b = new Bear().withName("jake"); // Breaks
bear b2 = new Bear().withFood("fish"); // Fine
```

The error given:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Animal to Bear

Apparently, when you return the base class this, it's returning a Bear type, and does not do any sort of automatic conversion.

What are my options to solve/bypass this issue?

Comment: You can, I didnt to be clear about which method worked, and which method did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```
public abstract class Animal<T extends Animal<T>> {
    protected List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

    public T withName(String name) {
        names.add(name);
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

This will give an unavoidable unchecked cast warning, since the type system cannot prevent you from writing `class Cat extends Animal<Dog> {} class Dog extends Animal<Dog>`.

If you have multiple builder methods in the base class, you can isolate the warning by writing `private T returnThis() { return (T)this; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Bear` class extends `Animal` and therefore inherits the `withName` method which is declared as

```
public Animal withName(String name) ...
```

Your method invocation is validated at compile time

```
Bear b = new Bear().withName("jake");  // Breaks
```

and all the compiler knows is that `Animal#withName(String)` returns an `Animal`. It cannot know that at run-time you are actually returning a `Bear`. So it cannot let you assign that value to a `Bear`.

You can do what [SLaks suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638868/438154) or override the method in `Bear` class and change its return type to `Bear`.

```
@Override
public Bear withName(String name) {
    names.add(name); // or invoke super method
    return this;
}
```

If you call the method on a reference of type `Bear`, the method will have a return type of `Bear`. [See here for why this works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type)

Comment: When I try this type of solution on my own problem, I get an error on `@Override` : `method does not override method from its superclass`.

Comment: @rocksNwaves That means you've changed the signatures of the methods in a way that the child one does not override the parent one.

Comment: I copy and pasted this example and your solution exactly, and it receives the same error. I have been told that is because the return type cannot be overridden (I just learned this in a question that I asked a few minutes ago). It must share the same return type or it is an example of overloading instead of overriding... Do you know a way around this?

Comment: @rocksNwaves The code in my answer assumes you're using the changes suggested by SLaks' answer, where `Animal` is generic and whose `withFood` or `withName` methods have the corresponding type parameter as a return type. If `Bear` is then declared to `extends Animal<Bear>` , you can override the method as shown.