# Return an object of child class from abstract base class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have classes that I want to (de-)serialize. I don't want the code to appear in every class, so I thought I'll make child classes like this

```
public class Swan extends Animal {}
```

and a base class like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {
   protected String name;
   // ...


   public void saveAnimal(String filename) {
       //ObjectOutputStream, save name...
   }

   public static /*returntype*/ loadAnimal(String filename) {
       //ObjectInputStream...
   }
}
```

**Basically I want this to work:**

```
Swan s1 = new Swan("name");
s1.saveAnimal("/pathToSaveFile");
Swan s2 = (Swan)loadAnimal("/pathToSaveFile") OR 
Swan s2 = loadAnimal("/pathToSaveFile")
```

How do I do this if Animal is abstract? If the method looks like this:

```
public static <T extends Animal> T loadAnimal(String filename) {
    //loadFromFile
    }
```

I cannot return `new T(name) //parameter cannot be instantiated directly`. I read a bit about reflection but you cannot get the class of a generic type T. The workaround for this is to pass the class of the type into a constructor, but Animal should be abstract.

Comment: Would this question help you out a bit?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638749/chaining-returning-base-objects-and-type-mismatch-to-extended-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to type erasure you can't do exactly what you want, but here is some code that shows three options:

```
public class Foo {

    public static class Animal {
        public void save(String filename)
        {
            // Write to file
        }
        public static <T extends Animal> T load(String filename, Class<T> cls) throws Exception
        {
            T result = cls.newInstance();
            // initialize result
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static class Swan extends Animal {
        public static Swan load(String filename) throws Exception
        {
            return load(filename, Swan.class);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Swan s = new Swan();
        s.save("somefile");
        Swan s2 = Swan.load("somefile", Swan.class);
        // OR equivalently
        Swan s3 = Animal.load("somefile", Swan.class);
        // OR also equivalent
        Swan s4 = Swan.load("somefile");
    }
}
```

In order to instantiate `T` you have to have access to the `Class` object so you can do `newInstance()`.  This requires a no-arg constructor or some more code to find and invoke the proper constructor, but that's basic reflection.  You can hide the need for the `Class` if you provide a `load` method in `Swan`.  Note that this is not an override, as inherited static methods don't participate in polymorphism.  `Swan.load` merely hides the equivalent method from `Animal`.

Comment: Ah ok, so I still have to pass the class of Swan.. as an argument. I thought there was another way like creating an object and type casting it or something like that. Thanks man!

Comment: Yes. You can almost get what you want with the third option, which buries the need for the `Class` object inside `Swan.load`.

Answer (score 0):

if you do this and then check the instance then it will work...

```
public static Animal  loadAnimal(String filename) {
    //ObjectInputStream...
}
```

## Example:

```
Swan s1 = new Swan("name");
s1.saveAnimal("/pathToSaveFile");
Animal s2 =  loadAnimal("/pathToSaveFile") //it is ok since Swan is an animal..
if(s2 instanceOf Swan){
    Swan sccc = (Swan)s2;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't want Animals to be instantiated. That's why I said class Animal is abstract. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @FrankHaubenreisser Animal  i not instantiated in this answer. it is just a type.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve it - create wrapper which contains instance type (Specific animal class) and the serialization body. So you will load type first, than instantiate and read the right class.

Comment: Why would this be necessary with `Serializable`? Shouldn't the data already contain type information?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in declaring a return type that is an abstract class. That’s an important tool in Object Oriented Programming. E.g., the methods `Arrays.asList(…)`, `Collections.emptyList()`, `Collections.unmodifiableList(…)` have in common that their return type is `List`, an interface. This does not imply that `List` in instantiated, as that’s impossible. It just implies that an unspecified subtype (implementation) of that interface is returned.

So you can simply declare your method to return `Animal` and let it return whatever the deserialization produced, if casting the object to `Animal` succeeded, it *is* a concrete subclass of `Animal`, perhaps a `Swan`.

If you want to remove the type cast at the caller side, you can provide the expected type as a parameter

```
public static <T extends Animal> T loadAnimal(String filename, Class<T> type) {
    //loadFromFile
    return type.cast(loadedObject);
}
```

which you can invoke as

```
Swan s2 = loadAnimal("/pathToSaveFile", Swan.class);
```

However, this does not provide more safety than an explicit type cast. There is no way to guaranty at compile time that a particular object loaded from an external file will contain a `Swan` rather than an arbitrary other animal.

This assumed that you deserialized the entire `Animal` instance, rather than properties of it. Otherwise, you could use the `Class` object to create the proper instance, e.g. via `newInstance` before reading its properties. But note that this is a questionable design. Normally, you create different subclasses, because they are going to have different properties.