# Dynamic return type of implementation declared in abstract method

Tags: java, generics, abstract

I am looking for a way to have, in an abstract method, the return type to be the one of the implementation calling the method.

In other terms, I would like to write something like that:

```
public class GenericClass {

  public <T extends GenericClass> T returnMyself() {
    return (T)this; // Compiler warning, unsafe cast
  }
}

public class Implem1 extends GenericClass {}

public class Implem2 extends GenericClass {}

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Implem1 implem1 = new Implem1();
    Implem1 again1 = implem1.returnMyself(); // Works fine, the type is inferred by the type of again1, I think
    Implem1 again2 = implem1.<Implem1>returnMyself(); // Works fine, the type is explicitly asked by <Implem1>
    Implem2 again3 = implem1.returnMyself(); // Works fine while it shouldn't. 
  }

}
```

What I am looking for is a way to declare the method so that at compilation time, returnMyself() can only return the type of the implementation invoking it (in my example, implem1 is of type Implem1), and ensure the code invoking cannot mistake/mix the types.

I searched quite a lot but couldn't find my answer anywhere (some topics seem similar but want a more general case, not explicitly the type of the implementaion invoking the method).

Some answers were correct, but always implied to override the method in each Implementation class, which may be cumbersome and bug-prone on my side. I'm ideally looking for a method that i would have to write only once in the Abstract class.

Any help/answer appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public class Parent {
    public Parent returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

This is no problem because if you store a `Child` instance in a `Parent` variable then you expect a `Parent` return type of `returnMyself()`. Even if it is actually a `Child` object, the `Child` returned by `returnMyself()` extends `Parent` so there you go.

Comment: While this does the trick, it requires to override each child class to write almost the same snippet of code (except the return type). I was expecting to be able to write it once and for all in the abstract class... But I guess it's not possible in Java?

Comment: Accepting the answer because it's the closest answer to my question, even though I kind of hoped there would be a more intelligent way :( Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention abstract in your problem description, how about follow a model similar to Java's [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class, where the generic type is in the class definition?

```
public abstract class GenericClass<T extends GenericClass> {

    public abstract T returnMyself();
}

public class Implem1 extends GenericClass<Implem1> {

    @Override
    public Implem1 returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Implem2 extends GenericClass<Implem2> {

    @Override
    public Implem2 returnMyself() {
        return this;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Implem1 implem1 = new Implem1();
        Implem1 again1 = implem1.returnMyself(); // Works fine
        Implem1 again2 = implem1.returnMyself(); // Works fine
        Implem2 again3 = implem1.returnMyself(); // Does not compile 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Oh the lazy days you just have go stackflow for some code instead of reading through javadocs, love it :p

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to write these methods inside of subclasses, this appears to be possible. You can override a method and have a different return type as long as the new return type is an extension of the old one:

[Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type)

Comment: Well precisely, I'd rather not write it again in each child class :D

Comment: You could return an Object instead :P I'm not sure you can do what you want.