# Access Parent Field with Child Object Java

Tags: java, c++

My Background is C++ and there we can access Parent Class's public Fields with Child Class Object. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    public:
        void show(){
            std::cout << "A";
        }
};
class B:public A{
    public:
        void show(){
            std::cout << "B";
        }
};
int main(){
    B obj;
    obj.A::show(); // it will print A.
}
```

How I can same thing in Java Inheritance?

```
public class Serial {
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Serial");
    }
}
public class Testing extends Serial
{   
    @Override
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Testing obj=new Testing();
        obj.show(); // it print Testing but how to Print Serial?
    }

}
```

I also have another question about overriding but due to Stackoverflow rules I'll ask as separate question.

So, what should be syntax to print/access Java's Parent class Method with Child Class Object Reference?
I tried. `obj.super.show();` etc but not works.

Comment: Hiding a base class's implementation in C++ is mostly a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

[`super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) can use only with in the class. Not outside of it.

Since you ovveride, you cannot call super method directly.

You are allowed to do only

```
obj.show();
```

If you still want to call super method you can modify your method as

```
 @Override
    public void show(){
        super.show();
        System.out.println("Testing");
    }
```

**Update :**

Coming to Parent and Child overriding return types,

This article might help

http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/11/covariant-contravariant-and-class-invariant-example-and-difference-in-java.html

Comment: SURESH why I can't call super in main? due to static keyword?

Comment: No. `super` can be only in child, not out side of that class.

Comment: @Suresh but main is also inside the child class.

Comment: @LetDoit In that case, because of static. You can use super only in instance methods and constructor of Child. Not in static methods.

Comment: Ok inshort there no way to access directly Parent class fields. Let me move to another question after reading your given link.

Comment: @Suresh I found my next question in your link. about different return type on overriding, I know overriding mean same signature, but if we not override and use different return type in child class then C++ allows it but Java not any reason behind this? and how we can do this?

Comment: @LetDoit Did you read whole article ?  `Below example shows you the same, Parent method returning Object and where as the Child method decided to return a specific type (String) where String is child of Object class. Hence covariance existed here.`

Comment: Yes I read complete article. But I'm asking about if in parent return type is `int` and in child is `void` or any other primitive type.. then?

Comment: @LetDoit No. you can't Java don't allow you to do that

Comment: Ok Suresh thanks for everything and I also read your article about Who you are on your link Nice then I decided I'm Programmer..!! :) and last question can you share any link that have info about why java not allow different primitive return type?

Comment: @LetDoit Here you go :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type