# Does it make sense to override a method in an interface

Tags: java, interface, overriding, extends

I have for example an Interface A and B. A has an (abstract) method called foo. B extends A.

It is possible to override foo in the interface B even with @Override, but is there any situation where that makes sense? There is nothing to override, because both methods have to be abstract and have no body. So I guess there is no situation where this makes sense, right?

So why is it possible to override in an interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One situation is when you want to update the Javadoc documentation to reflect a more specific contract in the method in the subinterface, as is the case with [`Collection#addAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) and [`List#addAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-):

- `Collection#addAll(Collection)`:

  > **Adds** all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection (optional operation)...
- `List#addAll(Collection`:

  > **Appends** all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's iterator (optional operation)...

A subinterface can also add a default implementation starting Java 8.

Comment: `addAll()` is a great example but perhaps you should show what the difference is in the contract.

Comment: Yes. This is called a Covariant Return Type. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_method_return_type

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom In my example both return `void` but the covariant return type feature still holds in general :)

Comment: Oops, yes, I see that now. :-)

Answer (score 8):

A subtype can impose more conditions, change the return type, change throw types. One example

```
interface AutoCloseable
    void close() throws Exception

interface Closeable extends AutoCloseable
    void close() throws IOException
```

(A subtype may also override with an erased version of the method signature... but that's old story)

In java8, sub-interface can provide a default impl for the abstract method

```
interface DummyCloseable extends Closeable
{
    default void close()
    {
        // do nothing
    }
```

Comment: What about type parameters? Can anything fun happen with those?

Comment: That makes sense, you mean a Covariant Return Type like that example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type

Comment: I guess, barring erausre,  they need "same" type parameters - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2

Comment: @stonar96 - yes, return/throw types of the sub-interface must be "compatible" with the super-interface :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have never heard about Covariant Return Type before. That's really interesting.