# Extra type parameter avoids invalid override error?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface like

```
public interface AnInterface {
    Consumer<Object> getConsumer();
}
```

And an implementation class like

```
public class AClass implements AnInterface {
    @Override
    public Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

This (correctly) does not compile since `Consumer<String>` does not extend `Consumer<Object>`.

However, if I change the interface to have an extra, unused type parameter on getConsumer, the error goes away and it compiles fine:

```
<T> Consumer<Object> getConsumer();
```

What's going on here?!

This occurs with javac in JDK 1.8 u20 and the Eclipse compiler in Luna.

Comment: Thanks for the really nice question.

Comment: weird that it does not compile in the first place, you should be able to override with more specific type in return that extends (is assignable to) the original type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type

Comment: @Hurda, this is not the same.

Comment: @kocko now I see the differnce, but this should be the same :-) another limitation of generics...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the code compiles, when you add the type parameter `<T>`, is that in this case you're overriding the *raw* `getConsumer()` method, i.e. you are not re-defining a type parameter (`<T>`), but you're just ignoring it.

It's worth mentioning that when extending raw classes or overriding raw methods, the ***whole*** generic information is just ignored, which means that in this case the compiler will not verify if the type parameter of the overriding method (`<String>`) is compatible with the type-parameter of the abstract method (`<Object>`).

If you had *kept* the method as generic, it would look like:

```
@Override
public <T> Consumer<String> getConsumer() {
   ...
}
```

and then the compiler would correct raise a compile-time error.

Comment: I thought something like this might be happening but I was confused since shouldn't it be an error that my class doesn't really implement the interface then? Do you have a link to more information about how this works?

Comment: Wait, how is it raw?  It seems to be concretely bound.

Comment: @Makoto, a method is generic if it defines a type-parameter (disregarding the return type being generic or not). When the interface's abstract method defines a type-parameter, but the implementing method doesn't care about it (i.e. ignores it), then the implementing method is raw. And when a method is considered as raw, then compiler ignores the whole generic information (including the one in the return type). Note that this, however, doesn't apply for methods that just *return* a generic type and don't implement another method.

Comment: @takteek, checkout [Angelika Langer's FAQ on Generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html). You will a lot there!

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this:

```
public interface AnInterface<T> {
    Consumer<T> getConsumer();
}

public class AClass implements AnInterface<String> {
    @Override
    public Consumer<String> getConsumer {
        return System.out::println;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach, but this doesn't really address *why* the other form works.

Comment: ...which is what my answer trying to do :)