# Can two overriding methods vary in return type in java?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, overriding

```
class ab {   
    int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class bc extends ab {
    String add(int a, int b) {
        return a + " " + b;
    }
}
```

If I am using JRE 5 will this code run? And what happens in JRE7 and JRE8?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type

Comment: This won't work in any of the three Java versions you mentioned. You can only *narrow* the return type in a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you redefine a method with a different  'return' type  in your sub-class,then it is not called over-riding unless the return type is similar(in your example one is string and the other is int-entirely different data types and so it is not over-riding).

Example:
Super class:

```
    public class mysuper
{
    byte  newfun(int a)
    { 
       return 11;
     }
}
```

Sub class:

```
    public class mysub
{

    int newfun(int b)
    { // this is over-riding,the body of the function is different and the return type is different but similar
      return 12;
     }

}
```

Covering up:

1.In over-riding,the function return type is exactly the same or something similar,only the body could be different.

Comment: "Overloading" means having different a parameter signature. So the example in the question would have been "overriding" (if it worked).

Comment: Having an entirely different return type would make it over loading!!

Comment: No, you can absolutely override a `Object getX()` with `@Override String getX()`. And you can not overload methods by just having two different return types in Java. `Object getX(); String getX(); ` will not compile

Comment: @Thilo edited the answer.Thanks a lot for letting me know.You are great!!

Comment: its an very old interview question , so Mathews Mathai , i consider this BUG or it will go into overloading category . because this was asked in Java interview

Comment: @user5598549 as Thilo said,overloading os only when the parameter changes!

Answer (score 1):

You can only vary the return types if they are related (or *covariant* to use the strict term). Broadly speaking that means that one is reference-castable to the the other: i.e. one is a child class of another.

So no in your case since a `String` is not related to an `int`: an `int` is a primitive type.

Comment: So going from `Object` in the parent class to `String` in the subclass would work, for example.