# Why would somebody cast instead of returning a subtype

Tags: java, inheritance, subtype

When overriding an inherited method, is there any reason to not declare the type a sub-type of of its original type? (Animal instead of Bunny see below)

Here is an example with bunnies.

```
public class Junk2 {

    public static abstract class Animal {
        public abstract String makeSound();
    }

    public static class Bunny extends Animal {

        @Override
        public String makeSound() {
            return "hop hop";
        }

    }

    public static abstract class AnimalHome {

        private final Animal animal;

        public AnimalHome(Animal animal) {
            this.animal = animal;
        }

        public Animal getAnimal() {
            return animal;
        }

    }

    /**
     * I am a bad bunny-hole, you don't know I am giving you a bunny
     *
     */
    public static class BadBunnyHole extends AnimalHome {

        public BadBunnyHole(Animal animal) {
            super(animal);
        }
    }

    /**
     * I am a good bunny-hole, I'm still an AnimalHome because
     * Bunny is a sub-type of Animal
     *
     */
    public static class GoodBunnyHole extends AnimalHome {

        private final Bunny bunny;

        public GoodBunnyHole(Bunny bunny) {
            super(bunny);
            this.bunny = bunny;
        }

        public Bunny getAnimal() {
            return bunny;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bunny bunny = new Bunny();
        GoodBunnyHole goodHole = new GoodBunnyHole(bunny);
        BadBunnyHole badHole = new BadBunnyHole(bunny);

        Bunny bunnyBack1 = goodHole.getAnimal();
        Bunny bunnyBack2 = (Bunny)badHole.getAnimal(); // look now I need to cast, I'm a crap BunnyHole

        System.out.println(bunnyBack1.makeSound());
        System.out.println(bunnyBack2.makeSound());
        System.out.println(bunnyBack1 == bunnyBack2);
    }

}
```

We can see that with the bad bunny hole one needs to cast to turn the animal back into a bunny. I think this is really bad but I see it allot at the moment, and wonder if there may be a reason for this. This makes as much sense to me as declaring the return type of makseSound as Object instead of a String.

Probably the best bunny-hole would go like this

```
public static abstract class AnimalHome<T extends Animal> {

        private final T animal;

        public AnimalHome(T animal) {
            this.animal = animal;
        }

        public T getAnimal() {
            return animal;
        }

    }

    public static class BestBunnyHole extends AnimalHome<Bunny> {

        public BestBunnyHole(Bunny animal) {
            super(animal);
        }
    }
```

But anyway I can't do that in my codebase at the moment. But my question still remains as to why the BadBunnyHole? I have even seen this horrid thing:

```
public static class BadBunnyHole extends AnimalHome {

        public BadBunnyHole(Animal animal) {
            super(animal);
        }

        public Bunny getBunny() {
            return (Bunny) getAnimal();
        }

}
```

To me, casting like this smells like a OO design flaw, but is there any reason in Java to do this? Was there a time you couldn't declare the return type a sub-type without breaking the interface? Or maybe some obscure reason if one is working with the reflections library?

Comment: You should clarify where you mean "return" and where you mean "have declared return type".

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt your right, sorry that's how I talk to myself in my head, changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When overriding an inherited method, is there any reason to not
>   declare the type a sub-type of of its original type?

If the method that overrides the superclass method *always* returns a subtype of the declared return type in the superclass, then there is no reason not to declare the sub-type as the return type in the subclass.

> We can see that with the bad bunny hole one needs to cast to turn the
>   animal back into a bunny. I think this is really bad but I see it
>   a lot at the moment, and wonder if there may be a reason for this.

I think that many people just don't know that it is possible to make the return type narrower when you override a method.

> I have even seen this horrid thing:
>
> ```
> public static class BadBunnyHole extends AnimalHome {
>
>     public BadBunnyHole(Animal animal) {
>         super(animal);
>     }
>
>     public Bunny getBunny() {
>         return (Bunny) getAnimal();
>     }
> ```

That goes to the different between how overriding methods and fields is done. In this case, if you intend to have subclasses of AnimalHome, it's probably not a very good idea to *store* the animal in the superclass. It's a better idea to make the superclass `abstract` with an abstract method `getAnimal()` that is implemented in each subclass, and to let each subclass have storage (a field) of the correct type of animal. Like your `GoodBunnyHole` example except that `AnimalHome` is like this:

```
public static abstract class AnimalHome {
    public abstract Animal getAnimal();
}
```

> To me, casting like this smells like a OO design flaw, but is there
>   any reason in Java to do this? Was there a time you couldn't declare
>   the return type a sub-type without breaking the interface? Or maybe
>   some obscure reason if one is working with the reflections library?

It has "only" been possible to do this since Java 5. From my non-representative experience, many people still don't know that it is possible.

See also [Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type)

Answer (score 1):

Using the generics in this scenario would be *far* more preferable, but the real reason this breaks down and you *require* the cast is due to the fact that the parent class doesn't know enough about what it should return.

The only place that `getAnimal()` is defined is at the parent, and the only type that can be safely returned is `Animal`.  Next, the reason that you're forced to cast is due to the fact that an `Animal` isn't guaranteed to be a `Bunny` (although the inverse is true due to inheritance).

The reason that you'd do this normally is if you're forced to.  The code is written in an inflexible way such that the types aren't possible to infer.  The only other thing here is that if you're doing a cast, you *must* be sure that you're casting correctly, or a `ClassCastException` can occur.

As an example:

```
Bunny bunnyBack2 = (Bunny) new Object();
```

That's valid, but will result in the CCE as mentioned above.

Again, using the generic types here would be far safer, since you're able to rely more on the compiler to sort out the types and casts as opposed to the developer having to do any sort of casting.

Comment: But is there any advantage of declaring getAnimal in BadBunnyHole type Animal instead of Bunny?

Comment: @Snickers3192:  Not really, no.  It moves the cast from one spot to another, and you're really not gaining much.  On the plus side, though, you don't have to cast it when something else uses it downfield; on the down side, you still have to cast.