# Creating a new subclass in superclass method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an abstract superclass that has concrete methods used by my subclasses. In at least one of my methods, I would like to return a new object of the same type.

For a better example I have a class A with a field (int num). I have class B which extends A and I create a class B object named classB. classB.someMethod should square num and return a new class B object with this squared value. I don't want to alter the original instance.

I've read about reflection a bit because that's what came up a lot during my searches. newInstance() was suggested frequently. I've also read that reflection can be bad. Is there a better way to go about with what I am trying to do? It's for a personal class I'm creating for openGL programming and could do it many ways but always try to practice keeping things as simple as possible. I could elaborate on my class if needed.

```
public class A(){
    private int num;

    public A(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public A square(A a){
        temp = a.num * a.num;

        return new class same type as the sublcass(temp);
    }
}

public class B extends A(){
    public B(int num){
        super(num);
    }
}

public static void main(String...args){
    B first = new B(4);

    B second = B.square();
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return new B(whatever);`?

Comment: Hi @spysmily1. It's hard to visualize the code that you're talking about based on your description. You might have better luck getting a solid answer if you add your code as a minimum, verifiable, reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post the actual code that the question is about.

Comment: I updated with code. Hopefully that helps someone see what I am trying to do.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Well there could be a C, D, E, etc... subclasses. I am looking for the return to be based on the calling subclass. So the return class could be either of those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hook method (abstract method in superclass), to generate instances of the subclasses.

If you want to have the specific return type in the superclass, then you need a type variable, holding the most specific class reference. Just keep in mind, that this makes your code more difficult to understand.

Like this:

```
public class A<SUB extends A<SUB>> {
    private int num;

    public A(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public SUB square(){
        int temp = num * num;

        return newInstance(temp);
    }

    protected abstract SUB newInstance(int temp);
}

public class B extends A<B> {
    public B(int num){
        super(num);
    }

    protected B newInstance(int temp)  {
        retunr new B(temp);
   } 
}

public static void main(String...args){
    B first = new B(4);

    B second = first.square();
}
```

Comment: I never thought of that. I searched everywhere and couldn't find that. It was also hard to find the right search words to use. Thank you for that idea. I haven't searched hook method yet but is it good practice?

Answer (score 1):

You can override methods as long as the type is assignable to the parent one. You can see its definition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14694885) and apply it to your code using the following pattern.

```
public class A {
    private int num;

    public A(int num){
        this.num = num;
    }

    public A square(A a) {
        temp = a.num * a.num;

        return newInstance(temp);
    }
    protected A newInstance(int num) {
      return new A(num);
    }
}

public class B extends A(){
    public B(int num){
        super(num);
    }
    public B square() {
      return (B)super.square();
    }
    protected B newInstance(int num) { // Yes, this is allowed
      return new B(num);
    }
}

public static void main(String...args){
    B first = new B(4);

    B second = B.square();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference link too. I gave the above as an answer cause he was first.

Comment: Hey, np! There are two solutions to your issue. I just felt I had to make it complete by providing this other answer. Also, you don't have to justify which answer you give the "accepted" tag: that power is yours and yours alone ;)