# How to create multiple getters in java with different return values?

Tags: java

Dummy question from php world. In php I would simply do:

```
class myClass {
   private $value; //can be anything. int, String, boolean, float

   public function getValue() {
      return $this->value;
   }
}
```

Suppose I have to program in Java now and I fail with this:

```
public class myClass {
   private int myInt;
   private boolean myBoolean;

   public int getValue() { return this.myInt; }
   public boolean getValue() { return this.myBoolean }
}
```

Is there any work around except naming methods like `getMyInt()` and `getMyBoolean()` ?

**Yes I know, Java is strongly typed language and I will always know the returned value.**

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: In java Object can be anything. Something like that in your mind? Still you'd need to convert when using... Or maybe you want generics... What is the use case?

Comment: You cannot overload a function solely on the return type.

Comment: @chepner, ye IDE told me the same. thats why I am asking for work around.

Comment: @paisanco, question has nothing to do with inheritance

Comment: @ksno well actually it does, because that's the only restricted case where something like this could be done, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type to see why.

Comment: I disagree that this is a complete duplicate.  There are mechanisms such as `public <T> T getValue(Class<T> cls) { ...` that will approximate what the OP is asking for.  I could un-dup-hammer this but will wait to see if anybody else agrees it merits being reopened.

Comment: Does those mechanisms work with primitive data types?

Comment: @JimGarrison granted it's somewhat debatable but I don't think there is a way to do what the OP wants in the way the OP wants.

Comment: That sounds like a potential answer to the dupe target @JimGarrison, since the question are arguably the same (btw, you can ping the person that closed with the hammer, this way they get notified ;) ).

Comment: Think about what would happen if your class has more than one variable of the same type - for example, `int x1; int x2; ` What would a getter look like? `int getValue() { <what here?>;` How would you know which int variable to return? That's why you use a separate getter for each variable: `getX1()` and `getX2()`

Answer (score 0):

In Java it will be a bad practice, although you can do something as below

```
class MyClass{
    private Object genericTypeObj;
    public void setObject(Object o){
        this.genericTypeObj = o;
    }
    public Object getObject(){
        return this.genericTypeObj;
    }
}
```

In above approach, type safety is compromised, You can also try generics to overcome the bad effect.

```
class MyClass<E>{
    private E genericTypeObj;
    public void setObject(E o){
        this.genericTypeObj = o;
    }
    public E getObject(){
        return this.genericTypeObj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically in the Java world we follow the JavaBean format for defining getters and setters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans

In your example class you would have something like this for the getters and setters:

```
public class myClass {
    private int myInt;
    private boolean myBoolean;

    public int getMyInt() { return this.myInt; }
    public void setMyInt(int i) { this.myInt = i; }
    public boolean getMyBoolean() { return this.myBoolean; }
    public void setMyBoolean(boolean b) { this.myBoolean = b; }
}
```

Comment: The question asked here is as how to have a reference which can be assigned a value of any type and how to have a getter of this generic reference.