# Java. Method Overriding and narrowing return type

Tags: java, methods, types, overriding, covariant

Ok so i'm new to java, so this might be a silly question. In my superclass there is a method that takes in a generic Object and returns an Object. In my subclass I am trying to override/narrow the method to return an abstract class I've defined elsewhere. Essentially all that this override needs to do is preform the same method but with Object replaced with the narrower class. How do I go about doing this?  It should only be a line or two of code, but i just don't know the syntax for it.

So in the SuperClass Foo there is a method like:

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public Object doSomething() {
        Object objVar;  
        //does stuff to objVar
        return objVar;
    }
}
```

Then a constructor for an object in a diff java file:

```
public abstract class Zee {
     //constructors & methods for zee
}
```

Then in a Subclass:

```
public class Subbie extends Foo { 
     @Override
     public Zee doSomething() { //covariant return type?? maybe?  


     return //needs to preform the same actions 
            //as the super doSomething method, but with 
            //the narrower return type.
     }  
}
```

Comment: Show the code or nobody can help you.  Please [edit] your post and include a [mcve] demonstrating your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. To check the syntax for narrowing return type see this: [Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type) (basically you're doing this right)
2. To invoke method from parent class use `super.doSomething()`
3. You can't instantiate an object of abstract class. You should extend it and return object of extended class