# Java: Is there a way to get methods with different return types in a enum?

Tags: java, methods, enums

I know that its not possible to use generics with Enums but im searching for a way to implement a method for a enum with *different return types*.

For example I have following enum:

```
enum TestEnum {

    TEST_INTEGER() {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue() {
            return 123;
        }
    },

    TEST_STRING() {
        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return "Test";
        }
    };

    public abstract Object getValue();
}
```

In this case `TEST_INTEGER` and `TEST_STRING` are implementations of `TestEnum`.
Thats why the method `getValue()` has the return type `Object` and not `Integer` or `String` when the `getValue()` is invoked. That means in each case I have to cast to the concerning Classtype.

Is there any better way to get diretly the different Classtypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, java allows to "reduce" the return type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type)).

But in your context, this does not make sense conceptually!

Think of

```
TestEnum someEnum = ...
Integer val = someEnum.getValue();
```

How is the compiler supposed to know **which** one of your enum constants you actually assigned to that value?

Therefore the compiler could only understand:

```
 Integer val = TestEnum.TEST_INTEGER.getValue();
```

But well, what if you just know that it is **some** instance of TestEnum you are dealing with?!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `<T> T` rather than Object, Java will do an unchecked conversion, depending on the implemented returntype of the `@Override`:

```
public abstract <T> T getValue();

...

String s = TestEnum.TEST_STRING.getValue();
Integer i = TestEnum.TEST_INTEGER.getValue();
```

Using a wrong "assignment" will cause a ClassCastException during runtime. Thus it might sometimes become hard to debug, if the actuall types are not obviously.

Comment: The fatal flaw with this approach is that it requires the client to know what different return type to expect for each different constant, a violation of the Law of Demeter, among other things. If the enum constant is passed to the logic in a variable, the client won't know what the return type will be, will it? This is a flawed solution, maybe because the OP has a flawed problem. They need a better type analysis. Java doesn't support non-covariant return types.

Comment: @LewBloch I know that this is not optimal, especially when multiple people are working with the code. (I would never use such a thing in an API used by others) It is "okay", if you have a smaller project where you want to quick-and dirty store different types (i.e. host/port etc..) It would be better to have static types inside a static class (Works as well in terms of autocomplete), however a enum can be iterated programmatically, for static types you would need to use reflection.