# Force subclasses to use type parameter

Tags: java, generics

When I create a class with a type parameter:

```
public abstract class AbstractBox<T> {
    abstract T getContent();
}
```

then I can still create a subclass without a type parameter:

```
class SomeBox extends AbstractBox {             // DISALLOW THIS
    @Override
    Something getContent() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Can I somehow force subclasses to provide a type parameter (even if it's just `Object`)? For instance, I want to disallow the above but allow:

```
class SomeBox extends AbstractBox<Something> {  // ALLOW THIS
    @Override
    Something getContent() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type). That question asks if overriding methods can return subtypes of the type parameter.

My question asks if I can enforce that any subclass of an abstract with a type parameter *must* provide a type parameter.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder To notify other developers on the project that subclasses should provide a concrete type parameter because they only make sense with that type parameter in the context of the domain.

Comment: Then this should really be handled with a code analyzer tool which would balk at raw types.

Comment: That's what the compiler and IDE warnings are for.

Comment: You mean the subclass must declare it's own type parameter? Or it must provide one for `AbstractBox`?

Comment: @FWeigl: I'm afraid I'm not getting it. But if you want to allow `class Foo extends AbstractBox<String>` but disallow `class Foo extends AbstractBox`, my answer below doesn't do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if `AbstractBox` is provided with a type parameter when extended you can do this:

```
abstract class AbstractBox<T> {
    protected AbstractBox() {
        // First, find the direct subclass of AbstractBox
        Class<?> cls = getClass();
        while(cls.getSuperclass() != AbstractBox.class)
            cls = cls.getSuperclass();

        // Then, check if it's superclass is parametrized
        if (!(cls.getGenericSuperclass() instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Must parametrize the extension of AbstractBox.");
        }
    }

    abstract T getContent();
}
```

Getting the direct subclass first is needed so that it doesn't break in the case where a direct subclass extends `AbstractBox` with a parameter, and is then subclassed again.

Note that this will also accept the case of `SomBox extends AbstractBox<String>`.