# Interview questions about memory in JVM stack and method overloading

Tags: java, polymorphism

Please help me to find answer of below two question, both asked in java interview:

1. In which case memory will allocate in JVM stack(nothing will be in heap) using new keyword.
2. In which case method overloading will be decided based on return type, method name and parameters are same (I replied that is not possible in java)

As per as my knowledge and finding from google, both can't be done, 
 My answer was:

1. New will always allocate the memory in heap and it can be refereed by reference from stack
2. Overloading decided on compile time, it will give compiler error in case it is not following the method below cases

   - Both must have the same method name.
   - Both must have different argument lists.

But he was not convinced.

Comment: I am not sure why thumb down for  questions, this is not my questions, I would like to know. Is both question is correct or not? I didn't find the answer in google, so asked here.

Comment: 1) **Never**. `new` always allocates from the heap. --- 2) **Never**. Method signature is name and parameter types. If two methods only differ in return type, it's a compile error. --- They are both trick questions.

Comment: I given same answer but he was not ready to accept, he told me both scenario is possible... might be he was confused... Thanks for answer.. that would help.

Comment: @NishantRaj I can only guess at other people's motivations, but the downvote button includes as part of its criteria: "This question does not show any research effort". Whether you've *done* research or not, your question doesn't *show* any research effort.  All it says is "I am not able to find the answers".  I would suggest that you [edit] your question to include what work you've done to research this, and the results you've obtained so far.

Comment: @azurefrog : that make sense, thank you... but i tried lot to the find the answer and finally posted here,

Comment: @NishantRaj another reason people might have downvoted is because your original title *"Please help me to find answer of below two question, both asked in java interview"* looks low quality and/or spammy - try using keywords from your post in the title next time.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to both is **Never**, since 1) `new` allocates from heap and since 2) method overloading is based on method name and parameter types, but not return type.

> [Interviewer] told me both scenario is possible

1. It is *theoretically* possible for the JVM's optimizer to perform escape analysis and decide to allocate an object on a stack, but that is impossible to predict, and depends entirely on the JVM implementation.

   The question "In which case ..." cannot be answered, since there is nothing you can do to make it happen, so no "case" can be setup to do it.
2. In the JVM itself, at the bytecode level, method signature actually do include the return type, so at that level, it's possible to have two methods that only differ by return type.

   It's not possible to *write* two methods in Java that only differ in return type.

   It is possible to write code that causes two such methods to be generated, however one of them is an internal *synthetic* method that just calls the other one. This happens when you override a method and narrow the return type.

   ```
   class A {
       Number getNumber() { ... }
   }

   class B extends A {
       @Override
       Integer getNumber() { ... }
   }
   ```

   Since the return type is part of the signature at the bytecode level, the compiler has to create a *synthetic* bridge method to actually override `Number getNumber()`. That method simply calls the `Integer getNumber()` overload.

   The ability to change the return type when overriding wasn't added to Java until Java 1.5.

   See also: [Can overridden methods differ in return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14694852/5221149)

I think they are stupid questions for an interview, because whether you can answer this or not doesn't in any way affect your ability as a Java programmer. The questions would only matter if you were being hired to write a *JVM implementation*, not if you were being hired to write Java code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The “stack allocation” is a tenacious myth. There’s *Scalar Replacement* which means, no object allocation will happen at all. Java object allocations happen in the heap memory [by definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se11/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3). Regardless of how a JVM implements it or what properties the memory has from a native code point of view, the objects are in the heap memory, as that’s what makes that memory the “heap memory”.