# Does two generics method at the same call can cause a compile error when trying to use them?

Tags: java, generics, methods

I'm read Deital's book :"Java How To Program", and in Generic Chapter the sentence is written:"If the compiler doesn’t find a method declaration that matches a method call exactly, but
does find two or more methods that can satisfy the method call, a compilation error occurs".
Can someone give me an example of the situation, because when i didn't success to get the above compile error.
my code:

```
public class Animal
{
    public Animal ()
    {

    }

    public String bark()
    {
        return "Animal";
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal  
{
    public String bark()
    {
        return "howhow";
    }
}

public class DogSon extends Dog
{
    public String bark()
    {
        return "I'm  Dog Son";
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        DogSon d = new DogSon();
        System.out.println(t.helpMethod(d));
    }

    public <T extends Dog> String helpMethod(T dog)
    {
        System.out.println("aaa");
        return dog.bark();

    }
    public <T extends Animal> String  helpMethod(T animal)
    {
        return animal.bark();
    }
}
```

Since there isn't method that get exactly son object, and there are two generic methods that can be suit here. Isn't this the situation Deital talking about?

Comment: Nope, erasures are different, and one method is more specific than the other.

Comment: In such cases, one with a more appropriate return type is matched. If none is more appropriate (specific) then an error would be thrown , for clarity read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type#targetText=Yes%20it%20may%20differ%20but,subclass%20of%20the%20object%20returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to understand is called [Erasure of Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html)

It means, the method's type parameter is converted to Object if it's **unbound**
or
it's *first* bound class when it's **bound**.

**Bound** means, -staying at your example- you have declared a relation of the type parameter T to another class, like you did:

```
// 1. method  
public <T extends Dog> String helpMethod(T dog)
// 2. method
public <T extends Animal> String  helpMethod(T animal)
```

**T** is **bounded to Dog** in the 1. method, and **bounded to Animal** in the 2. method.

So, when it comes to compiling, Java changes the **T** into Dog in the 1. method, and to Animal in the 2. method.
There is no ambiguity here, they are two different methods.

However, if you would declare a 3. method:

```
// 3. method
public <T> String helpMethod(T dog)
```

Then the **T** is **unbound**, you haven't declared a relation between T and another class, therefore when it comes to compiling, Java changes the **T into Object**.

Now, if you would try to declare a 4. method:

```
// 4. method
public  String helpMethod(Object dog)
```

There would be a **compilation error**, as the 3. method during type erasure would have the exact same [method signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) as your 4. method.
The compiler cannot decide which one you want to call, and throws an error.

With the above in mind, the **short answer** is:

In you code, you are using two different methods, there is no ambiguity, so no error occurs.

If you want to see that compilation error, you should declare another generic method which signature after compiling would be the same as an existing generic/non-generic method in your class.

Comment: Your explanation is clear. But the author is talking about _calling the method_. If the problem is like the one you talked about, so what is the matter of talking on the method call?

Comment: The compilation error would probably thrown at the line where you trying to call a method on such class with ambiguous methods. If you would try to compile the class without calling its methods explicitly, the error would occur as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot, unfortunately i will never know for sure what exactly the author mean.. I feel that there is something there that i'm missing

Comment: No worries :) I dont think you missed anything important. If you understand what I, and the other folks have written here you will fairly well understand this specific topic. Good luck on your journey learning Java, I highly recommend you to do the OCA exam if you plan to work as a Java dev, as well as the book: OCA: Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide: Exam 1Z0-808 by Scott Selikoff, Jeanne Boyarsky (Paperback, 2014) as it walks through every topic very well...then test yourself at Enthuware and you will be good to go  ;-)

Comment: Sorry i'm little bit confuse. You suggested me to do the OCA exam, where can i find it? under "Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide" book?

Comment: In addition, maybe you can explain why 'rzwitserloot' code isn't being compiled?  he disappeared :)

Comment: The exam is offered by Oracle, and the book helps you prepare for it. The book is good even if you dont do the exam to understand the important Java concepts ;-) If Ill have time tomorrow Ill try to check that out, but until then, if you could upvote my answer/mark it as answer that would be much appreciated ^^

Answer (score 2):

Not quite; in your example, the `T dog` variant is more specific than the `T animal` variant, and therefore, it is the one selected.

I cannot guarantee that I know what the author is referring to. But I can guess:

```
public class Example<T> {
    public void m(T arg) {
        // At compile time, 'T', as it has a lower bound of Object,
        // is treated as Object. Its signature therefore does not clash
        // with the next m, and thus this can be compiled.
        System.out.println("T-based");
    }

    public void m(Dog arg) {
        System.out.println("Dog-based");
    }
}

new Example<Dog>().m(new Dog()); // this line causes a compiler error.
```

The error generated is:

```
Animal.java:16: error: reference to m is ambiguous
    new Example<Dog>().m(d);
                      ^
both method m(T) in Example and method m(Dog) in Example match
where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Example
1 error
```

So, what's going on here: At compile time (Of Example.java itself), the two `m` methods are not neccessarily ambiguous yet; The T-variant is treated, for most purposes, as if it was equal to its lower bound (so, Object), and in java you can have an `m(Object arg)` and an `m(Dog arg)` in the same class, no problem.

However, after generics, the 2 `m` methods effectively DO clash: They now both take as argument anything of type `Dog`. Thus, it is no longer possible to call either m method on any `new Example<Dog>`. The proper solution is not to overload (that's what it is called when you have 2 different methods that have the same name) when generics is involved and the type params could overlap. Presumably, the author of that section of your book is trying to tell you WHY you should never overload in such a case.

Comment: I understand your explanation, but in your example there is one method (the one that get Dog a parameter) that is exactly match the method call. In the sentence i took from the book it is written : "If the compiler doesn’t find a method declaration that matches a method call exactly..", but here as i said, the ,method call and method declaration are exactly matched

Comment: Yes, and the code you pasted compiles, and works. Did you run it? It prints 'aaa'. It does NOT generate a compiler error.

Comment: Yes, it is. But in my comment i refer to the code you have posted

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're not getting a compilation error in your case is because both the methods

```java
public <T extends Dog> String helpMethod(T t) {

    return t.bark();
 }
```

```java
public <T extends Animal> String helpMethod(T t) {

   return t.bark();
}
```

tell the compiler to resolve `T` to `Dog` & `Animal` respectively. Which is actually same as writing

```java
public String helpMethod(Dog t) {

    return t.bark();
}
```

```java
public String helpMethod(Animal t) {

    return t.bark();
}
```

As `Dog` & `Animal` are two different types despite being in a parent-child relationship. The compiler won't complain.

However, if you're looking for a compilation error, try this

```java
public <T extends Dog> String helpMethod(T t) {

    return t.bark();
}
```

```java
public <T extends Dog> String helpMethod(T t) {

    return t.bark();
}
```