# Java getter return type based on object type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

What I am trying to achieve is something like the following:

```
public class Foo {
    Object o;

    public Foo(Object o) { //takes object
        this.o = o;
    }

    public <T> T getO() { //the return type of this should be the object type
        return (T) o;
    }
}
```

For example:

```
Object o = "123"; // imagine this comes from external system and can be anything
Foo foo = new Foo(o);
String foo = foo.getO(); //returns String
```

I saw a few examples doing something similar using Google Guava **`TypeToken`** but couldn't get exactly the behavior I want.

Comment: Without `Foo` being a generic type, this can't work - how would the compiler know what to do with a call to `Foo.getO()`?

Comment: You need to make Foo generic or using reflection... Here something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want if you make Foo have the correct type

```
public class Foo<T> {
   T data;

   public Foo(T d)
   {
      this.data = d;
   }

   public T getData()
   {
     return data;
   }
}
```

Then your examples will work as:

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>("123"); //passing String
String foo = foo.getData(); //return String

Foo<Float> foo = new Foo<>(123f); //passing float
float foo = foo.getData(); //return float
```

**EDIT:** the original question was updated slightly. However, the basic problem remains that a Java method must declare its return type. One can get close if one can use `covariant` returns in some fashion by extending a hierarchy. There are examples [Overriding a method with different return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519797/overriding-a-method-with-different-return-types-in-java?lq=1) and [Can overridden methods differ in return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694852/can-overridden-methods-differ-in-return-type).

One could also consider a Factory pattern to assist with the approach. So it would be

```
Foo foo = FooFactory.geetFoo(originalData);  // the specific foo would vary
String s = foo.getData();
```

Comment: So in other words it's impossible if you don't know the object type?

Comment: @StoyanDekov You are correct. It's impossible to know the object type of the return value at compile time, if you don't know the object type at compile time.

Comment: @StoyanDekov, I've looked at your example. I understand what you are trying to achieve. As the example is constructed, it is not possible. A Java method must declare its return type. I answered your original question. I am making an update to provide an potential alternative, but it is not exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade, you are correct, thank you. I copied the original examples and didn't get everything updated. Making the edit.