# Override a Super class method in JAVA

Tags: java

Super class

```
public class A{
    public boolean close(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class B extends A implements Closeable{
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

Implementing Close method of Closeable interface in class B gives error since return type void is not compatible with return type boolean of parent class. Signature of close method is different in parent class and that of interface. How can I resolve this issue?

### Update

Closeable interface also has method close() return type of which is different from that of class A:

```
public void close() throws IOException;
```

Comment: Change the return type in `B` to `boolean`. If you want to override a method its signature must be equal, i.e. the name of the method and the number and type of the parameters must be the same and the return type must be covariant (i.e. the same or a subclass of the overridden one - in your case `void` is _not_ covariant to `boolean`).

Comment: if you want to extend method from class A in class B you need to ensure signature will match., without that you will have different methods

Comment: Change `A` so the signature of `close` matches those of `Closeable.close`.

Comment: Do you have ownership of the `A`class?

Comment: No, I don't own class A.

Comment: only thing what you can really do, is remove closable interface from class B. there are no other solution

Answer (score 1):

Since no two methods with the same name and parameter list can exist in the same class. This is simply not possible without changing class `A`.

I think the best way to do this is to change the name of the `close` method to something else first. This is because people can't really infer what is the meaning of the return value just by looking at the word `close`. Does the boolean mean whether the thing is successfully closed? Or does it mean something else?

If a return value of `true` means that it is successfully closed, and `false` means it's not, change the method name so that it conveys this info! I suggest that you change it to `closeAndReturnSuccessStatus` or something like that.

Then, you can implement the method in `Closeable` this way:

```
public void close() {
    if (!closeAndReturnSuccessStatus()) {
        // throw an exception or something, since this means that it isn't closed.
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I just saw you say that you don't own class `A`, so maybe this will work:

Instead of inheriting, store an instance of `A` in `B`.

```
public class B {
    private A a = someValue;
}
```

and implement the interface like this:

```
public void close() {
    a.close();
}
```

Since this breaks the inheritance between `A` and `B`, it's not really a solution. But if that doesn't matter, you can add methods in `A` in `B`. Say there is a method called `someMethod`, you can just implement that method in `B` like this;

```
public void someMethod() {
    a.someMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant have two methods with same name which accept same arguments, and returns different type.

My suggestion will be to restructure your code, maybe to change `close` return type in class A to match interface, or maybe make A to implement your `Closable` interface

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change your parent class you can't solve this by inheritance.
Make A a private field of B and create a wrapper in B for any method of A you need.

Answer (score -1):

Your overridden method has to have the same signature than the super class method:

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public boolean close() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        // We'll never reach that point
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that this class can't implement Closeable because method signatures can't differ by just the return type. Since you can't change the signature of your parent's close() method you can't solve this problem by inheritance. Make B a wrapper class of A instead. Then B can implement Closeable and forward all other method calls to the inner instance of A.

Comment: This doesn't work. since Closeable interface method signature is public void close() throws IOException which conflicts with that of super class when implemented in child class.

Comment: @GautamKumar maybe you should mention about closable interface signature in your question

Comment: Parent's close() method can't be changed.

Comment: If you can't change your parent's method you can't implement Closeable because you can't have overloads that only differ by return type.

Comment: I already know that this is a bad answer (even doesn't compile) and I'm new to stackoverflow so can you please stop to vote down it further? That's not helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You answered the question yourself.

The `close()` method the parent class should always have the same return type (or a compatible one) as the one in the child class.

So you either have to:

- change the return type of the `close()` method in A
- change the return type of the `close()` method in B

It is possible to `@Override` a method with different return types, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519797/overriding-a-method-with-different-return-types-in-java) for more info-

Answer (score -2):

To override the method the return type should be same.

Replace void to boolean in your child class.

Super Class

```
public class A{
    public boolean close(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
public class B extends A implements Closeable{
    @Override
    public boolean close() throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: your class B wont compile, as return is unreachable statement

Comment: I just added that line, You have to use conditional statement also.

Comment: "You have to use conditional statement also." - What do you mean? There is no conditional statement that is needed.