# How to get a subclass to override a parent abstract method with an extended type?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, abstract-class, abstract

For example

```
public abstract class ParentClass {

    public abstract FooType getFoo();
    ...
}
```

and then something like

```
public abstract class SomeClass extends ParentClass {

    public abstract SpecialFooType getFoo(); //clashes with the parent!
    ...
}
```

In this case the getFoo() from SomeClass is supposed to be a FooType that implements the interface SpecialFooType. However I don't know how to set up the syntax for this.

Comment: Does `SpecialFooType` extend `FooType`?

Comment: @bradimus No. FooType is just its own class. But I want it to have other properties if you are getting FooType from that particular child class, which are defined in the interface SpecialFooType. In other words I want getFoo() in the child class to return something that is both a FooType and a SpecialFooType.

Comment: You can't do that since `SpecialFooType getFoo()` and `FooType getFoo()` will differ only in return type. They will have the same signature. You might could work it out if `ParentClass` were generic.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519797/overriding-a-method-with-different-return-types-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance is **more** than just putting **extends** on some class declaration.

For example, your classes have to follow the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). And that principle gives rules how **overridding** of methods has to look like.

It actually allows to **narrow** the type of return values; like: the base class has `Number getFoo()`; and the subclass can do `Integer getFoo()`. But in your case, the return types are **different**; therefore your idea is simply wrong on an **conceptual** level!

The reasoning behind that. If you have **client** code that invokes that method, the **client** must **not** need to know if it is calling that method on the base class ... or some subclass. In other words: the client code must be able to deal with a Number response, so of course, it will be able to deal with an Integer coming back. Now consider how that should work in your setup ... as said: it wouldn't!

And just for completeness: LSP says that *return* types can be *narrowed*, whereas method parameters can be widened. So when base foo() takes an Integer, subclass foo() is fine to take a Number.

Comment: I've seen the LSP mentioned many times but I simply do not understand the Wiki nor have I ever seen a SO answer that explains it in easy terms, so unfortunately it's not a principle I know how to apply.

Comment: I just updated my answer. If that isnt enough, I can give some more hints ... later on. Now out to walk the dog ;-)

Comment: A ghost cat walking a dog... that'd be wild to see.

Comment: You are welcome. I added another sentence about parameter types, hope that will help you to fully get into LSP. Thanks for the quick accept! And there wouldn't be much too see; its pretty pitch black night where ghost dog is walking his dog.